# Add hard coded text on caught parameter using Prism in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm passing parameters to my second viewmodel succesfully. However, I need to add some hard coded text on one of the parameters.

This is how i catch my Model from my second ViewModel:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        TodoItem = (TodoItem)parameters["Todo"];
    }
```

This is where I set the values in the second ViewModel. I have tried to set the `Title + "Test" = value.name` but it gives null:

```
private TodoItem _todoItem;
public TodoItem TodoItem
    {
        get => _todoItem;
        set
        {
            _todoItem = value;
            Title = value.name;
        }
    }
```

This is the Title string that I binded from Xaml:

```
private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to alter the Title due to a presentation requirement? In other words, do you need to change your title just to show on screen?

Comment: Do you mean that you set value to `TodoItem`,but get null ?

Comment: TodoItem is not null if I use the proper way of passing the parameter. This 'Title = value.name;' gives the the right string value. However, I would like to add text after the Title. So I tried 'Title + "Test" = value.name;' but then it says: "Left-hand side of assignment must be var, property or indexer. " @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: I tried various ways but none works. This gives null: 'var title = value.name; Title + "Test" = title;'

Comment: Ok, `var title = value.name` , and `Title = title + "Text" ` ,you can try this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked :) @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Ok ,it's Great！

Answer (score 1):

Setting this as @Junior Jiang - MSFT mentioned worked:

```
var title = value.name;
            Title = title + "Test";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a coalesce operator to guard against null values.

```
private TodoItem _todoItem;
public TodoItem TodoItem
{
   get => _todoItem;
   set
   {
     _todoItem = value;
     Title = value?.name ?? "";
   }
 }
```

In case you want to change your approach to a more declarative one, you can use a Converter.

```
    public class PrefixConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Prefix + value?.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

So , you can use in your XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Sample.Converters"
             x:Class="Sample.MainPage"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             Title="{Binding TodoItem.name,Converter={StaticResource PrefixConverter}}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <conv:PrefixConverter x:Key="PrefixConverter" Prefix="Test"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried this: Title + "Hello" = value?.name; but doesnt work. I only have 1 label that I need to add some hard coded text so converter seems to much. @Jesus Angulo

Comment: The label is shown in the first view but i also need it to be shown in the second view + add hard coded text.

Comment: Title + "Test" = value.name; Gives me this error:
Left-hand side of assignment must be var, property or indexer. @Jesus Angulo

Comment: If I do it like this: value?.name = Title + "Test"; its the same as above error.